# Dress code for Thesis Discussion

Tags: phd, thesis

Is there something like a "standard dress code" for a Ph.D thesis discussion? And, if there is - how important is it? Obviously, one should not (I think) dress *too casually*, but I do not know what is deemed appropriate.

I don't know how much this varies around the world; if it helps, I am from Europe.

Comment: "Europe" is a big place; at some European universities you'd be expected to dress like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=oxford+subfusc+gown&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=A5L&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=6TXeVLPiCpDWoAT-p4LQDQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=653#safe=off&channel=fs&tbm=isch&q=oxford+subfusc).

Comment: I assume a "discussion" means a defense (hence, why I marked it as a duplicate). If not, please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @ff524 it does, thank you! i tried looking around before asking, but couldn't find anything of the sort. i see i just choose the wrong wording for my search.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, different professors can have very different feelings about this. If you have any doubt, best to ask your primary adviser.

Answer (score 0):

I think it varies across cultures. Being a stereotypical italian, I think it is important to dress smartly and with style. Most importantly, however you dress, you should do it for yourself, rather than for the committee.

Clearly, if you go with a t-shirt and jeans, there might be those who think that you are not taking it seriously. But it depends on who these people are. Are they those who go to world-leading conferences and give a talk wearing shorts and a regular shirt? If so, you might be in trouble if you wear a suit!

The way you dress might be important for the first 5 minutes, afterwards it will depend on the work you have done.